# Elegant way to find if 4 strings (or N strings) are the same in Ruby

Tags: ruby

How do you find if N strings are the same in Ruby.

Say I have:

```
string1 = 'hi'
string2 = 'hi'
string3 = 'hi'
```

How can I find if the three are the same?

Comment: If you have them stored in an array you can iterate and `put` them into a map and check the size of the map when you're done (you want size == 1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The straightforward way is pretty elegant in its straightforwardness.

```
if string1 == string2 && string2 == string3
```

If you have an array, you can do:

- `strings.uniq.length == 1`
- `strings.count(strings[0]) == strings.length`
- `strings.each_cons(2).all? { |a, b| a == b }`

I particularly like the last one, since it works on all enumerables.

Comment: What about for N strings?

Comment: @HommerSmith: So you have an array of N strings? `uniq` is one way.

Comment: I like the last one too but how about: { |x, y| x == y }

Comment: @pguardiario: Sounds great! I didn’t know that was an option. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
[string1, string2].count(string3) == 2
```

I think this is efficient than others as it compares strings only N-1 times and doesn't modify the array nor generate intermediate arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Two of 752 ways:

```
a = ['hi', 'hi', 'hi']
a.uniq.size == 1 # => true
a.min == a.max   # => true

a = ['hi', 'ho', 'hi']
a.uniq.size == 1 # => false
a.min == a.max   # => false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(strings_array - [my_string]).empty?
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Set` based way.

```
require 'set'
[string1, string2, string3].to_set.size == 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [string1, string2, string3]
a.all?{|inst| inst == a.first }
```